# PHP strange behaviour: ReflectionClass::isCloneable() calls destructor?

Tags: php, reflection

Consider following code:

```
class A {
    function __construct() { echo __FUNCTION__ . "\n"; }
    function __destruct() { echo __FUNCTION__ . "\n"; }
}

$a = new A();
$c = new ReflectionClass($a);
$c->isCloneable();
```

Just instancing new class, and checking if it is cloneable using reflection.

The output is unexpected:

```
__construct
__destruct
__destruct
```

Why `__destruct` called two times? After looking into PHP source code, it seems that in `ext/php_reflection/reflection.c` ZEND function `isCloneable` occurs call to `zval_dtor(&obj)` when reflected object has no `__clone()` method defined. So, adding `__clone()` to class fixes the double destructor issue. What's that? Bug in PHP?

P.S. Tested in PHP 5.4 and 5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still an issue in 7.3.5 apparently.

Looks like calling isClonable runs the destructor.  It does not call the constructor.  If you add __clone, it calls nothing.

My solution was to make sure the destructor can run on an uninitialized class (other than the default settings of the member variables).

Submitted a bug report here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79115. It has been confirmed as a bug.

Comment: This bug has been fixed!